# Execution failed for task ':rive_common:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: android, flutter, cmake, android-ndk, rive

i face this problem when execute my code i searched for some solution but one solved even the solutions for flutter are rare

````dart
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.5.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  country_picker: ^2.0.20
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.2
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
  pinput: ^2.2.31
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  scroll_snap_list: ^0.9.1
  flutter_profile_picture: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+4
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  get: ^4.6.5
  page_transition: ^2.0.9
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  awesome_dialog: ^3.1.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.3.0
  location: ^4.4.0
  dio: ^5.2.1+1
```!
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rive_common:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.0.10\android\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\rive_common-0.0.10\android -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=19 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\startup\selkni\build\rive_common\intermediates\cxx\Debug\f694y5k4\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\startup\selkni\build\rive_common\intermediates\cxx\Debug\f694y5k4\obj\arm64-v8

i did use rive: ^0.11.3  but still didn't work for me
````

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It seems i downloaded flutter from snap. So i deleted from snap and reinstalled manually, then this problem fixed.

You can check this out on [github:](https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/323#issuecomment-1638880701)